# Where did I go wrong in my approach?

Tags: inequality

Consider the two inequalities: $y \le-1$ or $  y\ge 2$

My approach:

$y \le-1$ or $  y\ge 2$

iff $y+1\le0$ or $y-2 \ge 0$

iff $(y+1)(y-2)\le0$

On solving: $(y+1)(y-2)\le0$

I got $-1\le y\le2$

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: `iff (y+1)(y−2) ≤ 0` This is not an `iff`. Try $\,y=3\,$ for example.

Comment: Why on earth do you think ($a \le 0$ or $b\ge 0$) $\iff$ ($ab \le 0$)?  I cant think of any reason someone would think that were true.  It's obviously false if $a > 0$ and $b > 0$.  I guess you are confusing ($a\le 0$ or $b\ge 0$) with ($a \le 0$ AND $b\ge 0$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake has been pointed out in the comment.

Now the fix.

Case $1$: If $y+1 \le 0$ , then $y-2\le 0$, hence $(y+1)(y-1) \ge 0$.

Case $2$: if $y-2 \ge 0$, then $y+1 \ge 0$, hence $(y+1)(y-1) \ge 0$.